# How to arrange things (coordinate) in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a Tkinter window where on the right there is an image as below.

In the left of the image, there will be an Entry box with written answers.

Users can check whether the information is correct (if the answer question 30 is 1 the Entry box should be 1, in case if it is not 1, users could fix it)

My so far code:

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
root = tk.Tk()
im = Image.fromarray(img)
imgtk= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
image = tk.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.insert(tk.END, 'the answer').pack()

canvas1.create_window(50,50, window = entry1)
canvas1.create_window(50,100, window = image)  #I thought this would make it stood next to each other
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry, first time working with Tkinter, so my code may stupid

P/s: I know the shape of the image and the Y axis of every question to place the Entry box right next to it.

[image]

Comment: `.pack(side=tk.LEFT)`. See https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm for more options

Comment: The first two arguments of `create_window()` are `x` and `y`.  So if you want them side by side horizontally, you should change the  `x` value, but you have changed the  `y` value.  Therefore, it may be `create_window(50, 50, ...)` and `create_image(150, 50, ...)`.